# How do I match items in one list against items in another list in Python

Tags: python

Having trouble finding a python solution to matching elements of one list against elements in another list without a whole pile of "for" and "if" loops. I'm hoping to find a better way to do this. I have some big iterating loops that go through multiple lists to perform matches. On a match, I want elements of the list removed. Here are two examples:

```
def score_and_retweet(auth):
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    for tweet in api.home_timeline(count=100, include_rts=0):
        for goodword in tweet_whitelist:
            if goodword in tweet.text and tweet.retweet_count >= 2:
                try:
                    api.retweet(tweet.id_str)
                except tweepy.error.TweepError:
                    error_id = tweet.id_str
```

and

```
t = time.localtime()
    if t.tm_hour is 14 and (t.tm_wday is 1 or t.tm_wday is 4):
        htmlfiles = glob.glob(html_file_dir+'/*.html')
        for file in htmlfiles:
            for badword in filename_badwords:
                if badword in file:
                    try:
                        htmlfiles.remove(file)
                    except ValueError:
                        error = "already removed"
```

Comment: Can you sort the lists? If so you can do it in 1 scan.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but in your first example you can move the `tweet.retweet_count >= 2` condition outside of the `for goodword in tweet_whitelist` loop - there's no need to execute the loop if that condition is already false. (Ignore this if the `if` has an `else`.)

Comment: If maintaining order doesn't matter, there's `set`, and there's a recipe for ordered set out there too.  Then you get set operations, which do all this sort of thing for you.

Comment: Indeed, if order doesn't matter, make them two sets and then it's just `set1 ^ set2`.

Comment: In your second example is it sensible just to check for badwords in a filename what if the badword is *cock* and the file is *peacock*

Comment: It's fine for the badword to be greedy when matching against filename. I'm not worried about that. Is there a way to use "in" to match the content of an item in a set instead of the whole item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how much it would change in terms of performance, but you could write a filter function

For example in the second case (if you're looking for exact matches)

```
def fileFilter(f):
    if f in filename_badwords:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Then use:

```
goodFiles = filter(fileFilter, htmlfiles)
```

The advantage this has over set intersection is you can make the filter function as complex as you want (you have multiple conditions in your first example)

Answer (score 6):

Trying to answer this part of the question `matching elements of one list against elements in another list` could use `set()`, for example:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d','g']
b = ['a','c','g','f','z']

list(set(a).intersection(b)) # returns common elements in the two lists
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How could I do this in a "if X in Y:" sort of situation. I want to see if an item from list A is contained within one of the strings in B?